# Questions about GribBagLayout

Tags: java, user-interface, gridbaglayout

I'm working on a small program and am just starting with the skeleton of the GUI. I took a Java class a few years ago and I vividly remember using some kind of swing layout that supported methods like `addComponent(component name, row, column)` or something like that. I'm positive that it was passed the desired position of the added component in the form of row and column number.

I thought this was GridBagLayout, but as I've been trying it and looking up tutorials, I can't find anything like that. It does have a method `addLayoutComponent(component, constraints)`, but this doesn't let you declare the position right in the method call like I'm sure I recall doing. Is there another method or layout I should be using? I also recall that whatever layout i was using allowed me to call a `setColumnWidth(int)` method on a component to make it wider like that.

Does anyone have any ideas? Thank you!

Comment: There is a gridLayout that has that feature here https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/ui/GridLayout.html but I think that the functionality was taken out in newer versions or something because the current documentation has no such method.

Comment: Designing a GUI is not to be done by choosing one layout manager and fitting your screen into it.  I would recommend a good tutorial on Swing layouts, but I've never seen one.  The tour through the different layout managers in the Oracle documentation is about as good as it gets.  I think things are best done by understanding the overall purpose of each layout manager, and how to combine them to get the effect you want.  I personally despise GridBagLayout and delight in creating screens without it, myself, but I'm sure it also has its place.

Answer (score 0):

[SpringLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/spring.html) is awesome. It basically has anything you are looking for.

Try [WindowBuilder](https://eclipse.org/windowbuilder/) if you're looking for quick production.